# Ionic-3 error Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im Used `Ionic-3` and Im hide `Tabs bar` On `Specific pages`, Its working fine  but i have some issue, some time display this **error** message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

how to fix this issue,

this is my code

**check.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-check',
  templateUrl: 'check.html',
})
export class CheckPage {
  tabBarElement: any; // hidetab
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');// hidetab

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CheckPage');
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none'; // hidetab
  }

 ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'flex'; // hidetab
  }
  takeMeBack() {
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);  // backbutton
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this maybe it can fix your issue :

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
let tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    if (tabBarElement != null) {
      tabBarElement.style.display = 'none'; // or whichever property which you want to access
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir,I change like this now its work for me,  Thanks   `ionViewWillEnter() {
    let tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
    if (tabBarElement != null) {
      this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';  // or whichever property which you want to access
    }
  }`

Comment: Your Welcome.I'm glad that i could help you.